# Running R function with arguments in 32 bit R, inside 64 bit R

Tags: r, function, 32bit-64bit

Suppose I want to run the function

```
test.function <- function(arg1){
                    print(arg1)
                 }
```

How can I run, lets say:

```
test.function("Hello world")
```

in 32 bit mode, using 64 bit R? I have managed running an entire script in 32 bit mode using

```
 system(paste0(Sys.getenv("R_HOME"), "/bin/i386/Rscript.exe ",'"some_script.R"'))
```

But how can I change this, so that it can run a function with arguments, instead of an entire script?

EDIT

Following the answer by Roman Luštrik and running

```
system('Rscript test.script.R "hello"')
```

Gives me the following error:

> Error in winDialog(type = "ok", message = message_text) : 
>     winDialog() cannot be used non-interactively
>   call:  -> check.for.updates.R -> winDialog
>   Running stopped
>
> Warning message:
>   running command 'Rscript test.script.R "hello"' had status 1

(The error message was in my native language, so I had to translate a few words, so the text might differ slightly on other systems)

Comment: Can you put this line into your function?

Comment: Might be doable, but I havent come further, than running entire scripts, so I dont know how it should be done

Comment: Your edit seems like it should be a new question. In any case, you are probably using some functions which are not meant to be used non-interactively.

Comment: The function in the edit is an exact copy of the one you provided in your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find a solution myself, by modifying *Roman Luštrik*'s solution.

Following his example we have the script called `test_script.R`:

```
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)

test.function <- function(x) {
  print(x)
}

args.run <- list(x = args)
mydata <- do.call(test.function, args = args.run)
save(mydata, file = "Data.Rda") # If you need the output to an R object
```

Then in another script that runs 64 bit R, we can run this function in 32 bit R by:

```
pathIn32BitRScript <- '"C:/Some path/test_script.R"'
system(paste0(Sys.getenv("R_HOME"), "/bin/i386/Rscript.exe", pathIn32BitRScript, " ", "Hello world") )
load("Data.Rda") # Loads the results into an object called mydata
invisible(file.remove("Data.Rda")) # Deletes the file we created
```

In this example we have `x = "Hello World"`. In case you have spaces in your path you will need the double quotes as I have in this example.

Answer (score 2):

You can't run a specific function only, you will have to create a script. This does not stop you from creating a one-function only script, though.

If you create a script called `test.script.R` and put it somewhere where you can find it.

```
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)

str(args)

test.function <- function(x) {
  message("Your input:")
  message(x)
}

invisible(sapply(args, test.function))
```

Open up a terminal window. You can use Windows' `cmd.exe` (press Windows key and type `cmd.exe` or `Command Prompt` or whatever you have in your perhaps localized version of the system). Navigate to where the script is located and  run it using the below command.

```
$ Rscript test.script.R "hello" "hello" "won't you tell me your name" "i hate the doors"
 chr [1:4] "hello" "hello" "won't you tell me your name" ...
Your input:
hello
Your input:
hello
Your input:
won't you tell me your name
Your input:
i hate the doors
```

Or, you could use `system` to do the same thing through R.

```
system('Rscript test.script.R "hello" "hello" "won't you tell me your name" "i hate the doors"')
```

Notice the way I use single and double quotes. Single quotes are on the outer side. This call also assumes the script is located in the workspace where R is currently looking. You can change that using `setwd()`, though.

Comment: what exactly are you doing when you are running this script? I might have to mention I am using Windows 10 also

Comment: @Acarbalacar executing the one function which you would want to run directly. The script is just a wrapper around it, to catch arguments, do any potential preprocessing and then passing arguments to the function. The script above was run in a Windows machine, although through a `cygwin` terminal that is now embedded in RStudio.

Comment: this is a completely new world to me. I do use Rstudio, but I have no experience with cygwin. Could you edit your answer to provide a step by step guide to do this, or provide a link to a source that provides such a guide?